# .Net Web API IActionFilter.OnActionExecuted return type

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have an application on .Net Web API. After each action get executed, I want to take a look at result and change something in that.

Say my API controllerAction looks like

```
public Car Get()
{
  ...
}
```

After the action is executed, I want to modify the properties of return type in this case Car (but can be different for different action).

I know that IActionFilter.OnActionExecuted() gets called after an action gets executed. But I am not sure how to access the return type in this method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do this by looking at the response on the action executed context. If you want to get the car and modify it you could write something like this:

```cs
Car car;
if (actionExecutedContext.Response.TryGetContentValue<Car>(out car))
{
    // modify the car to send back in the response
}
```

If you want to check the type of the response, you could write:

```cs
ObjectContent objectContent = actionExecutedContext.Response.Content as ObjectContent;
if (objectContent != null)
{
    Type responseType = objectContent.ObjectType;
    // do stuff with the type
}
```

Comment: Also remember to add "using System.Net.Http;" at top of the class file  if you don't have it. "TryGetContentValue" is an extention method which is defined in this namespace