# Modify HTTP content in ActionFilterAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, actionfilterattribute

I have a controller action set up as:

```
[HttpPost]
[DecryptBodyFilterAttribute]
public InitializeSessionResponse InitializeSession([FromBody] InitializeSessionRequest request)
{
  ...
}
```

The http body is json and automatically gets de-serialized into my request object just fine. Now I want to have the http body content be an encrypted string that I will decrypt in an `ActionFilterAtttribute`. Encryption/decryption is not the issue. My issue is resetting the value of the body to a new value before getting to the action in the controller.

My ActionFilterAttribute looks like the below:

```
 public sealed class DecryptBodyFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
 {
    public DecryptBodyFilterAttribute()
    {}

    public override Task OnActionExecutingAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        string encryptedString = actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        //... decrypt do whatever and end up with the new content below...

        string newContent = "Something here would be the decrypted json of the initializeSessionRequest";
        //I need to do something like the below
        //actionContext.Request.Content = newContent;

        return base.OnActionExecutingAsync(actionContext, cancellationToken);
    }
 }
```

My question is similar to [Modify HttpContent (actionExecutedContext.Response.Content) in OnActionExecuted method of WebApi's ActionFilterAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16688248/modify-httpcontent-actionexecutedcontext-response-content-in-onactionexecuted) however that solution when casting the response.content (in my case request) I get a null object so that does not work for me.

Comment: did you find any solution for your question?

Comment: @User7291 I don't think I did and ended up doing it in each controller method :(